# Error inflating class ImageView and ImageButton both

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

I'm constantly trying to add Imageview inside my fragment Class but I'm getting Error and after I run the app, It stops with error of "Error Inflating class Imageview". But when I remove the Imageview and add Textview or Button only it works fine, Only with Imageview and ImageButton...It throws an error.

I tried changing android:src to app:srcCompat= but also it doesn't work and image file is very small in range of 60kb too.

Here is the Error log

```js
03-15 12:26:49.540 30218-30218/com.nepalpolice.cdp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
03-15 12:26:49.680 30218-30218/com.nepalpolice.cdp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.nepalpolice.cdp, PID: 30218
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nepalpolice.cdp/com.nepalpolice.cdp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageButton
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5018)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageButton
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                         at com.nepalpolice.cdp.dates.onCreateView(dates.java:36)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2239)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1332)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2063)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:554)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5248)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5018) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                      Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02006b
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:204)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:331)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:196)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:189)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:54)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:66)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:56)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:118)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1026)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1083)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:172)
                                                                      at android
```

and my fragment layout is

```css
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <!--TextView and Button displayed in First Fragment -->
<ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/eka"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:text="This is First Fragment"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/firstButton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

android:text="First Fragment"

android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and my fragment class is

```js
package com.nepalpolice.cdp;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * Created by Sagar on 2017/09/23.
 */


public class dates extends Fragment {


    View view;
    Button firstButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dates, container, false);
// get the reference of Button
        firstButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.firstButton);
// perform setOnClickListener on first Button
        firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// display a message by using a Toast
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "First Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton` instead of `ImageButton`

as you are using `app:srcCompat`

**Usage should be like this** :-

`android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton` -- > `app:srcCompat`

`ImageButton`         ---- > `android:src`

In your xml :-

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    .....
    .....
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/eka"
    />
```

Comment: nope it doesn't solve the problem still I'm getting following error FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.nepalpolice.cdp, PID: 3401
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nepalpolice.cdp/com.nepalpolice.cdp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton

Comment: then it must be your `image` check changing your image **`eka`** @BlueYeti81

Comment: yes I changed image couple of times but it doesn't help either.

Comment: Use `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton` for AndroidX

Answer (score 0):

Try use `android:src="@drawable/eka"` instead of `app:srcCompat="@drawable/eka"`